# Using amspset package

Tags: package-options

I use the `amspset` package.  I understand there are options to use the `cm` font (Computer Modern) and also an option called "unboxed" to remove boxes from the questions.  What is the correct command to activate these options?

I Use BaKoMa TeX on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Is `amspset` a special BaKoMa package? I couldn't find it on CTAN.

Comment: With the file not available, this question cannot be answered => 'not a real question'.